# intermittent JSON parse errors on mobile site

Tags: php, json

I have no idea how to solve a problem I'm running into, and I realize this will be hard for anyone to help me with, but I'm hoping that perhaps someone has experienced something similar and can at least point me in the right direction.

I have a web app that I built and my wife and I have been using it this whole year without any issues.  Then all of a sudden about a month ago, I started getting JSON parse errors only on the mobile version of the site.  I haven't done any work on the site for a while so no code has changed.

The weird thing is that the mobile version will stop working, but you can still use the desktop version without issue.  Then randomly after some amount of time has passed, the mobile version will start working again like nothing happened.   This happens on iOS and Android devices.

The app has a mobile version that uses something like this to detect mobile users:

```
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
 if(preg_match('stuff to match')
 header('Location: http://example.com/mobile.php');
```

When the issues are happening, it will place random numbers/letters on the page. I have a screen shot, but it won't let me post it because I don't have enough rep.  In the screen shot, there are  2 drop down menus, one for the month and one for the year.  To the left of the first drop down, it randomly put in "3e8", and to the left of the second drop down it put "94".  If I refresh the page, it will put different numbers and seems to get more messed up the more I refresh.  It will eventually start putting random numbers/letters in the drop down menus themselves.  I'm using a theme that has different skins, and it will even randomly switch the skin as well sometimes.

Has anyone ever experienced something similar before?  Could it have something to do with the PHP version?  While trying to research this issue, I found that I didn't have a PHP version set on the server, so I set that to 5.5, but that didn't resolve the issue.